# How can I add the authentication step in my script?

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I have a script below which I would like to schedule to run it everyday through SQL Server and store the calendar events to database but the problem is I would need to have my outlook open in order to run this script, how can I add my credential in the script so I don't have to open outlook and have the script run without keeping my outlook opened? Thank you

```
import win32com.client, datetime
from datetime import date
from dateutil.parser import *
import calendar
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Item = Outlook.CreateItem ( 1 )
Recip = Item.Recipients.Add ( 'Corporate Master Calendar' )

appts = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip,9).Items
appts.Sort("[Start]")
appts.IncludeRecurrences = "False"

eoy=date(date.today().year, 12, 31)
eoy=eoy.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
begin = date.today()
begin = begin.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

appts = appts.Restrict("[Start] >= '" +begin+ "' AND [Start] <= '" +eoy+ "'")

apptDict = {}
item = 0
for indx, a in enumerate(appts):
        organizer = str(a.Organizer)
        start = a.Start
        end = a.End
        subject = str(a.Subject)
        location = str(a.Location)
        categories = str(a.Categories)
        body=str(a.Body)
        itemid=str(a.GlobalAppointmentId)
        lmt=str(a.LastModificationTime)
        apptDict[item] = {"GlobalAppointmentId": itemid, "Organizer": organizer, "Subject": subject, "Location": location, "Start": start, "End": end, "Body": body,"Categories": categories, "LMT":lmt}
        item = item + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't - with MFA, even storing the credentials in the keyring (which only deals with basic credentials) won't do anything.

Comment: oh nooo thank you though really appreciate your response